# Win32 (GDI) - Set Opacity of STATIC Control

Tags: c, winapi, gdi, transparent

**I'm using C - (NO MFC or GDI+)** :-)

What I want is to set the opacity of my child window to let say 100 (my child window is a `STATIC` control). I was wondering if this is even possible and if so can someone please point me to the right direction on how to do it.

Here is my setup:

I create my Parent window as follow:

```
HWND     hWnd;
WNDCLASS wndCls_s;


wndCls_s.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
wndCls_s.lpfnWndProc   = MainWndProc;
wndCls_s.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wndCls_s.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wndCls_s.hInstance     = hInstance;
wndCls_s.hIcon         = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_BSN_64));
wndCls_s.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wndCls_s.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
wndCls_s.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wndCls_s.lpszClassName = pszCName;

if (RegisterClass(&wndCls_s) == 0)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;


/* Creating Window */
hWnd = CreateWindow(
    pszCName, pszCName,
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
    0, 0, WND_WIDTH, WND_HEIGHT,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

In my `MainWndProc`:

```
case WM_CREATE: 
    {   
    HWND hWndChild = CreateWindow(
        L"STATIC", (LPCTSTR) NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        10, 10, 110, 110,
        hWnd, (HMENU) (int) 10000, 
        g_hInst, NULL);
    }
    break;
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
    COLORREF dwColor; 

    dwColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    hDC = (HDC) wParam;

    //SetBkColor(hDC, dwColor);
    SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);

    /*
    This is not going to work for child window
    SetWindowLong(
        hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE,
        GetWindowLong((HWND)lParam, GWL_EXSTYLE) & ~WS_EX_LAYERED);

        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(
            (HWND)lParam, 0, 100, LWA_ALPHA);
        RedrawWindow((HWND)lParam, NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE | RDW_INVALIDATE);
    */

    if (g_hBrushRed == NULL)
        g_hBrushRed = CreateSolidBrush(dwColor);
    }
    return (INT_PTR)g_hBrushRed;
```

Comment: Not possible, only top-level windows can have the WS_EX_LAYERED style.  I suspect you're looking for WS_EX_TRANSPARENT.

Comment: @HansPassant, are you suggesting to use `SetWindowLong` on child window with `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`, and then process the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`? Then how can I set the opacity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you enable transparency with `TRANSPARENT` if you are going to return a valid brush for the background? You don't need `SetBkMode` and your red brush will be used by the control then.

Comment: Can you please explain more. Removing `SetBkMode` and returning the red brush won't transparency.

Comment: So you should have red opaque background, right? And what are you trying to reach, semi-transparent red background in term of alpha-blending, 100/255 blend with underlying image?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. So I can't return Solid Brush nor `NULL` brush (makes it fully transparent), so can please show me how to create transparent brush (do we even have that)?

Comment: You cannot do it in straightforward way buy specifying brush transparency level. What you can however do is to create/use temporary in-memory DC, request underlying windows(s) to paint into that DC, then paint your control image into another DC and then `AlphaBlend` one into the other coming up with final image for opaque presentation on the real DC.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to give it try.

Comment: Just a quick question, do I do all of those in `WM_CREATE` or `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`?

Comment: You actually don't need `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` at all anymore. It is a helper for default painting and you are going to take over drawing completely. You handle `WM_PAINT` (or control dependent custom-drawing, which is perhaps preferable), you can do everything there. If you are however going to pre-create some resources for reuse, such as bitmaps and device contexts, it would be a good idea to create them in `WM_CREATE` and destroy them in `WM_DESTROY`. The painting will take place in `WM_PAINT` anyway. You will also want to override `WM_ERASEBACKGROUND` with an empty handler.