# (GDI) AlphaBlend

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

This question is follow up [Win32 (GDI) - Set Opacity of STATIC Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643184/win32-gdi-set-opacity-of-static-control)

My problem is that my alpha blending function is not working and I was wondering if someone help me out?

Here is the Setup `WndProc`:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    OnChildPaint(BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps));
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
```

My `OnChildPaint` function:

```
BOOL
OnChildPaint(HDC i_hDC)
{

    HDC hMemDC;
    HGDIOBJ hOldObj;
    HBITMAP hBitmap;

    BLENDFUNCTION blendFunc_s = {AC_SRC_OVER, 0, 128, AC_SRC_ALPHA};

    hMemDC  = CreateCompatibleDC(i_hDC);
    hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hMemDC, 100, 100);
    /* hBrush  = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0)); */
    hOldObj = SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

    BitBlt(i_hDC, 10, 100, 100, 100, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    AlphaBlend(i_hDC, 10, 100, 100, 100, hMemDC, 10, 100, 100, 100, blendFunc_s);

    SelectObject(hMemDC, hOldObj);
    DeleteObject(hMemDC);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Have that in mind that I'm not working with actual Bitmap Image (There is no Image).

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect and what do you actually see?  The example code does not initialize the source bitmap.  Also, you've specific AC_SRC_ALPHA, which tells the function that the source bitmap has per-pixel alpha values (and that the pixels are pre-multiplied by their alphas).  Compatible bitmaps don't have per-pixel alpha values, so you're lying to AlphaBlend.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Thank for your reply. I have parent window which is popup and solid color. I have a child window and what I want is that my child window to be transparent (ie. 50%). I can't use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` and set `LWA_ALPHA` on child window because if I understand correctly child window inherent everything from it's parent so if parent isn't transparent child can't be (Corrent me if I'm wrong). Can you please show me an example on how to make my child window transparent?

Comment: That's a completely different question.  Try:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=transparent+child+window

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy That is not a different question. If you look at my post above I put the link in there that explained what I want. the solution to that was using AlphaBlend function. That why I'm posting this. The link you sent me is for the child control to be fully transparent which is not in my case. But thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry I missed the link.  I'm trying to help.  The question is tagged as GDI, the subject says it's about AlphaBlend, and the bulk of the post is about trying to use AlphaBlend.  Those are things I know about.  I don't offhand know how to make a static control a transparent window, but Stack Overflow seems to have dealt with lots of questions on that topic, which is why I suggested a different search.